# Can an error page (like 404) served without X-Frame-Options be exploited?

Tags: web-application, http

I'm checking some HTTP headers in the server response.
I get a 404 error page. Could in some scenario an attacker leverage a missing `X-Frame-Options` header in a 404 page?

Comment: That depends on what the error page contains

Comment: no more or less than any other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherent in a 404 response which protects against attacks like clickjacking (i.e. what `X-Frame-Options` tries to address). While most response bodies send with 404 are likely not vulnerable to clickjacking in the first place due to the shown content (i.e. just some more or less fancy error message), browsers do not add extra protection by themselves just because the response code was 404.

Comment: You are correct, there could be a fancy error page with clickable elements. -- but if the page is a standard 404 error page with no clickable content, there is no clickjacking risk.

Comment: @MarkKoek: Sure, if there is nothing to click on then no click can be hijacked.